# How to expand a collapsible item from link within another collapsible item [js]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I'm making a list of collapsible items that can make calls to itself to scroll to and expand other items on the fly. Shooting for this...

**Before selecting the hyperlink.**
[image]

**After selecting.**
[image]

**How can I get the First collapsed item to expand when the link to it in the Third item's paragraph is selected?**

**What I got**: If the example above had more collapsed items, then the code below would scroll the webpage to the desired collapsible item (half the solution).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <!--Import materialize.css-->
      <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div>
        <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i><a name="987"/>First</a></div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Hello StackOverflow! SO's da' bomb diggidy!</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i>Second</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><p>Why is the person who invests your money called a broker?</p></div>
            </li>
            <li>
              <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i>Third</div>
              <div class="collapsible-body"><p>I'd like to <a href="#987">open the First collapsible element</a> in this list.</p></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
      <!--Import jQuery before materialize.js-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would just trigger click event on first `.collapsible-header` item, with slightly changed html code for the anchor:

```js
$('[data-click]').on('click', function (e) {
    $( $(this).data('click') ).trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.3/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.95.3/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div>
    <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="accordion">
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i>First</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                <p>Hello StackOverflow! SO's da' bomb diggidy!</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i>Second</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                <p>Why is the person who invests your money called a broker?</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="collapsible-header"><i class="mdi-navigation-chevron-right"></i>Third</div>
            <div class="collapsible-body">
                <p>I'd like to <a href="#" data-click=".collapsible .collapsible-header:first">open the First collapsible element</a> in this list.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Same code is also on **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt5515zt/1/)**.

If you wish to target n-th element, than you can use [jQuery :eq() selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (zero based). For example, to target 3rd item you would use `'.collapsible-header:eq(2)'` selector.

---

If you **care about the SEO** (and you should), than your links should have correct `href`. In this case add unique IDs to `.collapsible_header` elements and use slightly different script to exploit it:

```
$('[data-click]').on('click', function (e) {
    $( $(this).attr('href') ).trigger('click');
});
```

where the target item is:

```
<div id="about_stackoverflow" class="collapsible-header">
```

and the valid local link is:

```
<a href="#about_stackoverflow" title="Click to open first item" data-click="true">open the First collapsible element</a>
```

You can see it working on **[this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zt5515zt/2/)**. (The last anchor may be anywhere on the same page)

Comment: Works like a charm. In all seriousness, @skobaljic - you're Awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Other than being able to dynamically open the last note by using the qualifier `last`,  I can't modify which note I'm opening per your anchor implementation `<a href="#" data-click=".collapsible .collapsible-header:first">`. **How can I use this anchor to open _any collapsed item_ and NOT just the first or last one?**

Comment: You can add IDs to your `.collapsible-header`s and than use `'#your_id'` as a selector. If you wish to target n-th element, than you can use [jQuery :eq() selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) (zero based). For example, to target 3rd item you would use `.collapsible-header:eq(2)`.